# django: passing parameters in URLConf

Tags: python, django

I want to have this URL:

/weibo_login/?app=first

I want the URLConf to call my view function with parameters but I don't know how to write the URL dispatcher to pass 'app=first' to the view function. The original URLConf:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
(r'weibo_login/', 'weibo.views.mylogin'),
```

The view function:

```
def mylogin(request):
```

I want to pass 'app=first' to view function and eventually get a dictionary in that function, so that I can know every parameter passed in.

Any good suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view you should write sth like this:

```
def mylogin(request):
    app = request.GET.get('app')
    ...
```

URLconf stays same as you posted.
Generally you don't handle GET parameters in URLconf - this is job for views.